# InAppBrowser, Open Window, Post Message

Tags: javascript, android, inappbrowser, postmessage

Is it possible to open a site in an InAppBrowser, have that site use `window.open` to open another window, then send a message to that other window (and vice versa)?

Answer (score 7):

Postmessage is already implemented on not released version. You can fork the most recent dev version on inAppBrowser from their git page: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/
Before building it  remember to remove the current component and add the most recent dev version for using it.
As its described in their documentation you can dispatch postmessage like:

```
inAppBrowserRef.executeScript({ code: "\
            var message = 'this is the message';\
            var messageObj = {my_message: message};\
            var stringifiedMessageObj = JSON.stringify(messageObj);\
            webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage(stringifiedMessageObj);"
        });
```

Or from inside inAppBrowser's app its something like:

```
  const message = 'message'
  const messageObj = {message: message}
  const stringifiedMessageObj = JSON.stringify(messageObj)
if (window.webkit && Window.webkit.messageHandlers) {
      console.log('postmessage call on webkit')
      window.webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage(stringifiedMessageObj)
    }
```

And you can listen for it inside cordova like:

```
this.inAppBrowserRef.on('message').subscribe((event) => {
      console.log(' postmessage received')
      const postObject:any = event
      if(postObject.data.message){
         console.log(postObject.data.message)
      }

    })
```

Comment: tysm :). Main key here is  it needs object stringified (JSON) .. i was trying with simple string and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

**InAppBrowser has a limitation regarding two-way Communication**: InappBrowser doesn't allow continuous communication

**Solution 1 (Few Limitations)**

Using **IFRAME**:

```
var myIframe = document.getElementbyId(IFRAME_ID).contentWindow;
```

Send `msg` to `iframe` from parent window:

```
myIframe.postmessage("Hello World", "*")
```

Receive `msg` in `iframe` from parent window:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e)
{
    // add your code here
});
```

Send `msg` to parent window from `iframe`:

```
window.parent.postmessage("msg from iframe", "*")
```

Receive `msg` in parent window from `iframe`:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e)
{
    // add your code here
});
```

**Limitation:**

If you try to navigate from one domain to another in the end, you may get error related to x-frame-options.

---

**Solution 2 (Recommended)**

Use **cordova-plugin-wizviewmanager:** to send a message from one view another:

```
wizViewMessenger.postMessage(message_data, targetView_name);
```

To receive message from one view another:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event)
{
    // add your code here
});
```

**Advantages:**

- Directly communicate b/w App (mainView) to other custom (user-created) View.
- No error related to x-Frame Options

**Github Link:**

https://github.com/Wizcorp/cordova-plugin-wizviewmanager

Comment: wizviewmanager is completely outdated now.