# Cannot postMessage from inappbrowser to Cordova application

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm using this module (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) for the ability to open external links within my Cordova application. However, `postMessage` example from documentation doesn't work.

I need the ability to be able for an `inappbrowser` instance to communicate with the parent (the `opener`). Given that there is no `opener` object with the `inappbrowser`, I've looked through repo's documentation and tests, and I cannot reproduce the `postMessage` API to communicate between an `inappbrowser` instance and the main Cordova application (parent).

Here's a simple example taken from the documentation/test within this repo:

```
const ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');

ref.addEventListener('loadstop', () => {
  console.log('loadstop has been fired'); // this fires

  // when this has been executed, `webkit` variable doesn't exist inside of the `inappbrowser`
  // instance
  ref.executeScript({
    code: `(() => {
      var message = "TESTING!!!";
      webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage(JSON.stringify(message));
    })()`
  });
});

// this is never fired
ref.addEventListener('message', (...args) => {
  console.log('MESSAGE RECEIVED FROM IN_APP_BROWSER', ...args);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is pointing to a version that has not yet been released. I pointed to the `3.1.0-dev` version of this package and the implementation works like a charm.

Comment: Hello Detuned, Can you please explain how did you point it to dev version. I am stuck at same position. triedyour code, it does not enter into the script. what else changes are needed.

Comment: @Detuned How do you send message from the openend url in the InAppBrowser to your app to activate the message event listener?

Comment: @Detuned - Is this feature now available on the master branch? (e.g. I don't need to pull from a separate branch?)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the InAppBrowser does not yet have **postMessage** implemented. The only solution in this case would be to use an **iframe** to receive postMessage from your external webpage. [This has been discussed earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47330075/inappbrowser-open-window-post-message) on this site too.